# WSO2 ESB message processor - logs

Tags: message, processor, wso2-esb

I configured a message processor in ESB WSO2. every now and then, all the messages are not carried out and they stay pending in the queue (message broker)
I can I can find only this log in the ESB console
"BlockingMessageSender of message processor [SAPMoveMaterialMessageProcessor] failed to send message to the endpoint"

My questions:
1, how and where can I see the real reason (detailed logs, error msg) why the message processor could not be sent out? I have defined a Fault sequence on the message processor but shows nothing

2, in case that I get this issue in the production environment is there a way how to "copy" a pending message (from the message broker queue) to my DEV environment and debug it there?

thank you very much for your ideas!

Answer (score 0):

1. AFAIK you can get more details from enabling DEBUG logs related to message processors. You can get these in the server management console tools- >'logging' and doing a search for matches which contains 'messageprocessor' and make the log level to DEBUG.

eg: 
org.wso2.carbon.message.processor.service.MessageProcessorAdminService
org.wso2.carbon.message.processor.MessageProcessorServiceComponent

2. As a solution for this you can try out by using a clone mediator (the use of clone mediator here is to make multiple identical copies of the message) inside the fault sequence (when pending message gets fail to consume) to persist to a database - may be to your dev environment.